# After installing OTRS on XAMPP the server responds with An internal error occurred

Tags: php, apache, xampp, otrs

I installed the program otrs, but how I do it with xampp How do I run the program?

And XAMPP Apache CONF

```
DocumentRoot "C:/otrs/OTRS/bin/cgi-bin"
<Directory "C:/otrs/OTRS/bin/cgi-bin">
```

localhost/installer.pl

Chrome Print:

> Server Error!
>   An internal error occurred on the server because the server can not meet your request.

How do I run xampp OTRS with respect to this matter.

Answer (score 0):

your best bet is NOT to try and use XAMPP but just go with the Windows Installer you can download from the website. Using XAMPP and Perl apps will be slow and not an enjoyable experience.

If you need to use XAMPP for some reason, you can. You'll be missing some perl libraries which is the reason for your error message. Run the checkmodules script located in the `bin/` directory of your OTRS install: `perl bin/otrs.CheckModules.pl` --> it will report you all the modules which you need to post-install.

Comment: I fully understand if you tell a bit more detail would be very happy Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing some Perl modules required for OTRS to work.
To check which modules are missing run `perl OTRS_DIRECTORY/bin/otrs.CheckModules.pl`
After that you need to install all missing modules.